# Power adapter for Europe - Type C or Type E/F?

Tags: europe, power

Traveling to Croatia & Germany from the USA next week. Need some adapters. Early research says they use both Type C and E/F in Europe. So, which adapter is the most universal?

I believe Type C adapter will work with Type E/F outlets (as well as Type C outlets). Can anyone confirm this or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 6):

Although Germany uses Type F, in a few days visiting it I found a few outlets of C type. In Croatia almost every outlet is F type.

Using a type C adapter would work on any case, as it has the same separation (19mm between the center of each pin) but thinner pins (4m vs 4.8mm). The only con is that it would fit a bit looser and will be easier to unplug it accidentally.

Most of the "universal travel adapters" choose to go with the C type to cover the 3 kind of outlets.

Answer (score 6):

A "Type C" adapter will work fine in Type E and Type F sockets. From [AC power plugs and sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#CEE_7.2F16_.22Europlug.22_.28Type_C.29):

> The separation and length of the pins allow its safe insertion in CEE 7/1, CEE 7/3 "Schuko", CEE 7/5, and most Israeli, Swiss, Danish and Italian sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I have a wall unit from Germany with the E/F plug which is round and thicker, than a Dutch windmill light that uses a C Plug smaller and thinner round plug.  Amazon has a good selection of adapters.  Read the specs before you buy, some adapters say C/E/F can be used which I bought.  Keep in mind they only change the plug size, they don't convert any voltage.  That's a separate product!

Answer (score 0):

Type C is limited 2.5 amps and does not proved a ground connection so that limits the types of appliances that can be safely connected. It does however fit more types of sockets.

Comment: 10 and 16 amp versions of type C also exist